# Power Automate: Write empty date field to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I created a PowerAutomate flow that reads data from an excel file and writes to a SharePoint List. When it tries to write a date field that is empty, I get the error message below

```
OpenApiOperationParameterTypeConversionFailed. The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/field_9' is required to be of type 'String/date'. The runtime value '""' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'String/date'.
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?
And also any thoughts on how to obtain the column ID would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check if the date column is empty, if true, keep the date column blank too in SharePoint list, else, add the date as shown below:

```
addDays('1899-12-30',int(items('Apply_to_each')?['Date']),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Julie_MSFT
I used your scheme and I am now getting this error:
                                                                                                                                                                     
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_item_3' inputs at line '1' and column '28546': 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'.

Comment: My Syntax is  :            addDays('1899-12-30',int(items('Apply_to_each_2')?['date']),'yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: When you list the rows in the table, is your date column numeric?

Comment: Hi Julie. I did a download from [List Rows Present in table]. Here is what the output looks like : 

"date":"2021-12-23". 
Seems like its a string, not numeric

Comment: If this, you can use the date column directly.